# VBA - Check mark with double clicking

Tags: excel, vba

I am not very familiar with VBA (just starting to learn) and I am trying to modify the following coding so that the target is not in row 1 of the current worksheet but it points to cell A1 to the "Calc" worksheet. Keep in mind that the "Calc" worksheet will then be hidden and locked.

In the end, what I would like to achieve is to double click on a cell and show/delete a check mark. Then, based on the presence or absence of the check mark do so other calculations.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As     Boolean)
If Intersect(Target, Range("E4,E6,I8,E10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
With Target(1)
.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
.Value = IIf(.Value = "ü", "", "ü")
Cancel = True
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("E4,E6,I8,E10")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Cancel = True
    With Target
        .Font.Name = "Marlett"
        If .Value = "" Then
            .Value = "a"
        Else
            .Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Remember that this goes in the **worksheet code** area.

**Note:**

- we set `Cancel` to avoid ending up in `Edit` mode
- we use `Marlett` with the lower case *a* to facilitate easy typing

Comment: Thanks.  So, if I understand correctly, there is no need to point to the value (ü) in the "Calc" worksheet.  Correct?

Comment: @user9284099  You are correct....the reason that you are correct is that all the ranges in your code are relative to the active worksheet...which is also the sheet in which the code resides........which is also the worksheet in which you are double-clicking...... **remember** do not  put this code in a standard module.